# Enable Application Express in Database Expresss

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-enterprise-manager

Currently I have installed Oracle Database Express edition. But now I need to work with Oracle Application express. So, now I need to enable or upgrade to Application express. Is there any possible way to do this? Thank You!

Comment: This question does not belong to this community

Comment: 11g already has Apex http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/upgrade-apex-for-xe-154969.html

Comment: Yahh. I got your answer. Thank you!